# What metals can be the substrates for magnetron sputtering?

Tags: experimental-physics, material-science

I am planning to produce thin films of amorphous silicon with magnetron sputtering. The articles I reviewed seem to be using copper foil as substrates for magnetron sputtering:

> Thin copper discs (15.87 mm diameter, 0.3 mm thick) were used as substrates for electrode fabrication. [Sethuraman, 2011](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jpowsour.2010.06.043).
>
> Amorphous Si thin films of 50 nm thick were deposited on copper foil
> by means of direct-current (DC) sputtering. [Li, 2014](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/am5009419).

Will the quality of the deposited silicon film deteriorate if I choose to use other substrates, say, aluminium foil or titanium foil?

Comment: Depends on what material properties are important to you, and what further processing you do. For example, note that copper is a fast diffuser in silicon (crystal or amorphous) and has a near mid-gap state that will kill carrier lifetime. So, if you anneal an a-Si/Cu sample, you likely can't make high quality solar cells out of it...

Comment: @JonCuster from what I recall, aluminium diffuses equally good. However, I was thinking more about some substrates providing a better adhesion than the others.

Comment: Aluminum is a much slower diffuser than copper. It also has a low eutectic point, and is a p-type dopant, so doesn't kill carrier lifetime (an Al layer, carefully annealed, will melt in, providing backside p-type layer and ohmic contact in one step for photovoltaics). As for adhesion, well, that is what Ti and Cr are for...

Comment: @JonCuster can you expand (possibly as an answer) why Ti and Cr have better adhesion?

Comment: Ti and Cr are very (_very_) common adhesion layers in thin film technology. It is hard to find a sputter/ebeam/whatever system in a thin film lab without one or the other. They have very high affinity for C, O, and N, so they eat up any impurities at the original interface, as well as react with nitrides or oxides to intermix and form a strong bond. For example, silicon nitride is pretty darn inert, but chrome forms even stronger (i.e. energetically preferred) bonds, so chrome metal on silicon nitride will quickly react to form a strong chemical bond.